# Is there a Civicrm hook for new contact/user insert?

Tags: drupal, civicrm-entity

I want to create new users in Drupal 7 whenever there is a new contact created from the civicrm.

Also, how can I use the civicrm primary email address as a username in the Drupal 7?

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this post](https://civicrm.org/blogs/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-single-or-multiple-contacts-civi-imports-and-webforms), which uses CiviCRM Entity and Rules to create Drupal users when Civi contacts are created.

Within the CiviCRM Entity module, check out the function `civicrm_entity_action_create_user()` to see how the username is set. You could patch it to implement a way to choose a username field/pattern, rather than hard-coding it to the Civi Display Name field.

Comment: Thats great...but how can i make username same as email address

Comment: I edited the answer with an additional tip.

Comment: The latest beta version of CiviCRM Entity allows you to choose a format for the user name in the rule action edit form.  Use of the email address is now supported